# Импорт из Blender в Unity

Tags: unity3d, blender

создаю помещение в blender импортирую его в Unity, персонаж проходит сквозь это здание, в чем проблема и как это исправить?
 физика у персонажа стоит

Comment: А на здание коллайдеры повесил? Ригидбоди добавил?

Comment: коллайдер вешаю все равно проходит сквозь стены или же падает сквозь пол, ригид стоит и на персонаже и на стене

Comment: покажи скрины с компонентами на здании и на персонаже

Comment: на стене статическая физика?